# Passing Datagridview to dataset

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable, dataset

Hello internet so first i am newbie at c# and i am doing project about changing data from a sql table. I passed the result of the query to the datatable and datagridview, but what i want next is i want the modified datagridview table passing to a dataset. this is how i get my table from the sql:

```
string query = "select Article,Barcode,\"Minimum Stock\",\"Current Stock\" from article where Fid=2 and \"Minimum Stock\" > \"Current Stock\"";

           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
           conn.Open();

           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           da.Fill(dt);
           dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
           conn.Close();
           da.Dispose();
```

Now the users will modifie the table and valid the information. How can i save it to a dataset?
I tried to bind dataset to the datagridview:

```
Dataset1.Tables.Add(datagridview1.datasource);
```

But it threw a error where it says datasource doesn't use here
Can anyone help?

Comment: I would suggest, from my own recent experience, that you should move your project to WPF rather than WinForms, and use MVVM pattern data binding, and finally using LINQ to SQL data classes for your model.

Comment: Hello, this is very indeed interesting, but is there a way to move my winform  project to wpf project?

Comment: You must create a new project, and then using xaml layout the windows.  The logical code you can copy and paste into the new project files, but it takes some tweaking because WPF is a different set of controls (DataGrid rather than DataGridView for instance). For a good start use [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124160/Using-WPF-MVVM-for-Database-Access](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124160/Using-WPF-MVVM-for-Database-Access) as a reference, and will happily share my own experience doing the same thing for the past 6 weeks.

Comment: Another great article on MVVM and binding to WPF controls is [http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html).  It presents a couple of helper classes that you'll want to use to simplify the binding from xaml to view model.

Comment: Thank you i will try but i have a new problem, how can i remove rows in usercontrol?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by usercontrol . . . do you mean the xaml examples from the first link?  If so, I did not implement user controls in my windows.  Rather, I just laid out the controls in the xaml directly.

Comment: in winform, there is a option called datagridview1.AllowUserToDeleteRow, and i want this is wpf. Thank you for having wpf, but i think for now i will stick with winform. But DEFINETLY i will use WPF in the future.

Comment: Oh, I see.  In my WPF application I just select a row and hit delete and the row is deleted (there is a code step required to flow this change into the database).